# Authorize attribute is not working in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on a project in MVC 5 using Asp.net C#, since a long time, now the project is completed and I have to restrict the unauthorized access, but the Authorize attribute is not working.

This is some portions of web.config file

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Please define "Is not working". Any errors, exceptions, etc. ?. If I apply your config to a fresh asp.net mvc web application generated by visual studio, I still get an 401 error, when I am trying to access a secured resource.

Comment: @Marco "Is not working" means that it is not asking for login, instead it allows everyone to access a specific method of my application which is [Authorized]

Comment: Are you actually using `[Authorized]` and not `[Authroize]`?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but

shouldn't remove in

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

be removed?

Edit:

I fixed my problem by adding:

```
  app.UseMvc();
```

to my `Configure` class

and

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }
            );
```

to my `ConfigureServices` class

Hope that is of any help for you

EDIT2:

Take a look at this:

[If the app uses authentication/authorization features such as AuthorizePage or [Authorize], place the call to UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization after UseRouting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

So yea... Wasted hours trying to figure this out. Thanks Microsoft. Hopefully this was also your problem.